# OOO.OM formatting (Y axis) is not provided in superset

Tags: d3.js, apache-superset

How could I use OOO.OM formatting in superset?

There is some data like
" timestampA: 11748000,
timestampB: 11724000 "
and Y AXIS FORMAT is "Adaptive formating"

[image]

I need to display y axis value like OOO.O, OOO.OO, OOO.OOO ... dynamically.
How to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if dynamic as you have mentioned in the question is possible. But if you want OOO.OM then you can use `.4s` and similarly `.5s` for OOO.OOM and so on..